# error that returns me is `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. Even when I use `mike`

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I want [a chatbot](https://github.com/antoinecomp/bookchatbot) to record data in a MySQL database.
However I do not have much experience managing SQL databases with SQL.
I have an `ActionBookRoom` class in file [`action.py`](https://github.com/antoinecomp/bookchatbot/blob/master/actions.py) that calls a connection with SQL and would like to record the information I sent to it: `name_room`,`day`, `hour_start`,`duration` .

I know I have to make the connection to the database with:

```
cnx = connector.connect(host='I_really_don_t_know_what_to_use_here', password='my_pass_that_works_on_mysqlcmd', user="root", database="the_database")
```

I already have some problems to make the connection and, therefore, I have more problems to know how to store the data.

```
class ActionBookRoom(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_room'

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        print("inside run")
        name_room = tracker.get_slot('name_room')
        day = tracker.get_slot('day')
        hour_start = tracker.get_slot('hour_start')
        duration = tracker.get_slot('duration')

        booking_answer = make_a_booking(name_room, day, hour_start, duration)
        print("passed booking")
        if booking_answer:
            booking_answer = 'The reservation has been made'
        else:
            booking_answer = 'The room is taken at this hour'

        response = """You want to book the {} room on {} at {} for {}. Is it correct ?""".format(name_room, day, hour_start, duration)

        name_room = str(name_room)
        day = str(day)
        hour_start = str(hour_start)
        duration = str(duration)
        print("before connexion")
        #SQL queries#
        cnx = connector.connect(host='I_don_t_know_what_to_use_here', password='my_mysql_cmd_password', user="root", database="the_database")
        print("after connexion")

        dispatch = dispatcher.utter_message(response)
        dispatch = dispatcher.utter_message(str(booking_answer))

        return dispatch
```

The error that returns me is `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. Even when I use `mike`:

```
inside run
[2019-02-22 16:52:00,822] ERROR in app: Exception on /webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 179, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\rasa_core_sdk\endpoint.py", line 86, in webhook
    response = executor.run(action_call)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\rasa_core_sdk\executor.py", line 177, in run
    events = action(dispatcher, tracker, domain)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\actions.py", line 42, in run
    booking_answer = make_a_booking(name_room, day, hour_start, duration)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\booking.py", line 61, in make_a_booking
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(password='jeb41jeb', user="root", database="alex")
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 172, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 735, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 182, in _open_connection
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
2019-02-22 16:52:00 ERROR    flask.app  - Exception on /webhook [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 179, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function
    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\rasa_core_sdk\endpoint.py", line 86, in webhook
    response = executor.run(action_call)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\rasa_core_sdk\executor.py", line 177, in run
    events = action(dispatcher, tracker, domain)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\actions.py", line 42, in run
    booking_answer = make_a_booking(name_room, day, hour_start, duration)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\booking.py", line 61, in make_a_booking
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(password='jeb41jeb', user="root", database="alex")
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 172, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 735, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 182, in _open_connection
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I use `MySQLWorbench` but I'm still a newbie. I get access to MySQL 8.0 CLI with, say, `my_password`, get the users:

```
mysql> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+
| User             |
+------------------+
| mike             |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have `Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: YES)` even when I provide the password that worked or `mike`

Should I reinstall MySQL ?

## Update :

I reinstalled MySQL and tried it with the CLI and it works:

```
(staenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack>python
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>> db = mysql.connector.connect(
...     host="localhost",user="root",password="MySQL.2019",database="alex")
>>>
>>> cursor = db.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reservations")
>>> myresult = cursor.fetchall()
>>> for x in myresult:
...   print(x)
...
(1, 'red', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 8, 12, 0), None)
(2, 'red', datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 8, 12, 0), None)
>>>
```

But I still have the error when I try to do it from the file [actions.py](https://github.com/antoinecomp/bookchatbot/blob/master/actions.py)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following connector

```
cnx = connector.connect(host='I_really_don_t_know_what_to_use_here', password='your_password', user="mike", database="the_database")
```

In user argument add your `username`

Comment: Instead of `user` ?

Comment: No, add as below
`cnx = connector.connect(host='I_really_don_t_know_what_to_use_here', password='your_password', user="your_user_name", database="the_database")`
Replace *your_user_name* with your username. i.e `mike`

Comment: You can get user by entering `SELECT USER();` into your *mysql cmd*

Comment: got it, I got `root@localhost` when using `SELECT USER();`. Rather different from the results given by `SELECT User FROM mysql.user;`. Yet even when I was using `mike` it gives me back an error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` which is rather strange.

Comment: Sorry, Did you checkout password?

Comment: I use the one when asked while getting access to MySQL 8.0 CommandLine Client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188903/discussion-between-devang-padhiyar-and-thepassenger).